# How to get the current year to use this as a filter in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, get, onchange

On my page I display a number of results. I want the visitor to be able to apply a filter on the results, depending on the year. So, if the user selects the filter "2014" only the result of 2014 should be shown.

I've created this for the SQL so far:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
   if ($_GET['year'] == '2013')
     {
     $sql .= " AND year=2013 ORDER BY date DESC";
     }
   elseif ($_GET['year'] == '2014')
     {
     $sql .= " AND year=2014 ORDER BY date DESC";
     }
```

The filter is triggered by a `<a href>` tag, like this:

```
<select onChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_self')"> 
<option value="page.php?year=2013">2013</option>
<option value="page.php?year=2014">2014</option>
</select>
```

Basically, the `onChange` reloads the page, setting the year, using the `_GET` method.

This all works just fine. Except for one thing. I need to change the code every year manually, in order to keep the option values updated with the current year. So, as soon as a new year starts, I've to update the code myself. Is there a way to do this automatically?

**Update**

I have this script that creates the option tag, starting from 2012 and ending on the current year:

```
var filteryear = '2012';
var filtertill = new Date().getFullYear();
var foptions = "";
for(var fy=filteryear; fy<=filtertill; fy++){
  foptions += "<option value='urenregistratie_all.php?jaar="+ fy +"'>"+ fy +"</option>";
}
document.getElementById("filteryear").innerHTML = foptions;
```

So the problem isn't in the `<option>` part, it is the `MySQL` part that should increase with it...

Comment: Just a wee sidenote, Stack's syntax checker's buckin' about `$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name;` ;)

Comment: So, you mean I should better not use that line? Changed it, hope this is better?

Comment: `$sql="SELECT date,year FROM $tbl";` missing quote. That's what I meant by that ;)

Comment: Ah, small mistake, didn't notice that. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using something like this:

**HTML**

```
<select onChange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_self')"> 
<?php
$year = 2013;
while($year <= date('Y')){
    echo '<option value="page.php?year='.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
    $year++;
}
?>
</select>
```

**PHP**

```
$sql="SELECT date,year FROM $tbl";

$year = 2013;

while($year <= date('Y')){
   if($year == $_GET['year']){
      $sql .= " AND year=$year ORDER BY date DESC";
   }
   $year++;
}
```

Comment: But this continues all the way right? It doesn't stop at the current year

Comment: It will stop at 2014 this year and next year at 2015 and so on... The loop breaks as soon as $year is greater that the current year which is date('Y')

Comment: The problem isn't the option, it is the SQL. >>>>>>>> if ($_GET['year'] == '2013')
     {
     $sql .= " AND year=2013 ORDER BY date DESC";
     } <<<<<<<<<< This part should increase automaticly till one year in the future

Comment: You missed one, I fixed it.

Comment: Perfect, refreshed the page and saw your code :) That did the trick! Thanks. Small question though not really that important: if I change the value of `$year` to 2010, the first option that is shown is 2010. This option is not selectable. It is just there, clicking it doesn't start any action. I can offcourse change the year, starting 1 year earlier, but maybe you know something that will fix this? It's just to get it clean, again, nothing important

Comment: This problem is only on the first option that is shown. All other options work just fine!